# Distributed synchronized execution

Tags: java, distributed, execution, synchronized

I'm trying to accomplish something that in terms of concept is very simple to understand. I want to synchronize a block of java code between different machines. There are two instances of a programa running in different machines that cannot run at the same time.

I've heard of zookeeper, jgroups and akka too, but while reading the documentation it seemed to me a bit overkill for what I'm trying to do. Does anyone have any idea if there's anything more straight forward to use?

Thanks in advance,

Rui

Comment: "There are two instances of a programa running in different machines that cannot run at the same time." Any coordinator of these two programs must store state about the execution of these programs. What options are available for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not quit sure I understand the question. I'm not worry with the state of the running instances. I'm just worrying about they do not process data simultaneously.

Comment: If you are going to worry about whether the processes are processing data simultaneously, then there has to be some communication protocol that can reflect the state of the process to some coordinator. Or the coordinator must be capable of determining this without requesting processes for this information, which requires that the coordinator to store this info somewhere. In either case, the coordinator responsible for synchronization has to store synchronization state about the system as whole. The OS, the JVM etc. do this by tracking usage of semaphores, mutexes etc. and storing this info.

Comment: To add further, one of the answers mentioned using a database lock. My point is that an exact answer for your problem, will depend on how you will store this synchronization state information, and what primitives are you going to use (file, database, shared memory and IPC etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Hazelcast's Distributed Lock ( http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#lock ) may be helpful. Hazelcast is relatively lightweight so should hopefully not be overkill.

Comment: Thanks. I believe your solution fits what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

If all the technologies you mentioned (also take a look at [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org)) are too sophisticated for your needs, maybe simple database locking?

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement will lock given database record, making other clients running this query to block. Simple, yet safe and reliable.

Comment: I thought of that, doesn't seem a good approach. Is a single point of failure. Thanks anyway for the input.

Comment: @rpvilao - Like @VineetReynolds said, if you have additional requirements such as high availability, you need to clarify your question. Depending on your specification, some solutions may be too simplistic and some may be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

A very very basic solution would be using [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/index.html).

Decide to use one machine as master which has a method which uses a [mutex](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/concurrency/) lock to allow only one mthod caller passing.

This special method you have to call via RMI from all other slave instances before you run your special java code block.